# Hosting Django-Streamlit Integrated Web Apps

Tags: django, deployment, hosting, streamlit

I've developed a web application using Django that handles user authentication, including signup and login processes. Upon successful signup, the intention is to redirect the user seamlessly to a separate Streamlit application.

Detailed Overview:

Application Structure: The web app comprises two distinct components: a Django-based authentication system and a Streamlit-based dashboard or app.

Signup and Redirection: After a user successfully signs up through Django, the objective is to automatically redirect them to the Streamlit app without requiring an additional login.

Deployment Query: My challenge lies in understanding the deployment process for this integrated structure. I'm seeking guidance on how to host both Django and Streamlit apps in a manner that allows them to interact seamlessly after the signup process.

Specific Queries:

Hosting Strategy: Which platforms or hosting services would be suitable for deploying these two applications?

I'm relatively new to deployment and recently developed a web app using Django for user authentication (signup/login). Upon successful signup, I aimed to redirect users seamlessly to a separate Streamlit app.